# Remove duplicates from SQL Window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to sum values inside a window function but I can't figure out have to prevent summing duplicates. Below is a snippet of the results I have right now. For the last column I want to calculate REG_MOVEMENT summed across unique STORE_ID's and then divide it by the number of unique stores. This column should be 5603.5 ((9359 + 1848)/2) since there are 3 rows with the same STORE_ID and one different.

| KEY_ID | PRODUCT_ID | STORE_ID | REG_MOVEMENT | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 154 | 5214266 | 28002 | 9359 | 7481.25 |
| 155 | 5214266 | 28002 | 9359 | 7481.25 |
| 156 | 5214266 | 28002 | 9359 | 7481.25 |
| 173 | 5214266 | 28005 | 1848 | 7481.25 |

My current code is

```
SELECT
     KEY_ID,
     PRODUCT_ID,
     STORE_ID,
     REG_MOVEMENT,
     SUM(REG_MOVEMENT) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID) / CONUT(STORE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a distinct count in the denominator, but SQL Server does not allow this in a single count window function call.  As a workaround, we can use `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY STORE_ID) dr
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    KEY_ID,
    PRODUCT_ID,
    STORE_ID,
    REG_MOVEMENT,
    SUM(REG_MOVEMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID) /
        MAX(dr) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID) AS new_col
FROM cte
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, STORE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with a subquery to de-duplicate (store_id, reg_movement) rows:

```
select 
  KEY_ID,   PRODUCT_ID, STORE_ID,   REG_MOVEMENT,
  (select avg(reg_movement) 
   from (select distinct store_id, reg_movement 
         from Tbl) Unq
  ) As NewCol
from Tbl
```

(Tbl is yourtable)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT AVG(reg_movement)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT store_id,
        CAST(reg_movement AS FLOAT) AS reg_movement
    FROM Table1
) a
```

Comment: In general answers on stack overflow should be more than just code, please supply an explanation as to what your solution is doing